# "JUMP" in a java 2d game

Tags: java

I have this code and I wanted to initiate a jump in a java 2d game,the thing is that my object doesnt goes anywhere,it just stays there...i wanted my object to jump as i press the key and the programme to show me images moving up and down..i am trying to do this by simple repaint() method
CODE::::

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(hero.jump()==1){
    int jumpheight=40,j=0;
    while(j<jumpheight){
        hero.y--;             \\changing the y position (up)..
            try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
        repaint(); 
        j++;
    }
    j=0;
    hero.jump1=0;
    while(j<jumpheight){
        hero.y++;               \\changing the y position (down)..
            try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
        repaint(); 
        j++;
    }
    }
    else {
    hero.move();
    repaint();  
    }
```

Comment: I don't do a lot of Java GUI stuff, but if I remember correctly I recently had an issue that was solved by invoking the `updateUI` method on the `JPanel` I wanted to repaint.  If you post your full code, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Don't forget to tag your homework as: "homework" ....?

Comment: Are you sure that your actionPerformed function is getting called?

Comment: (1) For  better help post a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html). (2) Do not in any case block the EDT! (`Thread.sleep(100);`).

Comment: You might want to ask this on the gamedev stackexchange site instead: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the position change into another thread. The key processing and the redraw is now handled in the same thread in the code you have now. When you call *repaint()* a repaint is scheduled, but not performed until the event thread is "free" again, but since you have a loop (with sleep) it is never free and instead your repaint will happen after your loop is done (and your hero is back at the original position).